# Tkinter Simple Markdown Parser - Remove markdown tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on a simple markdown parse in tkinter. Concept being that headings can be surrounded by asterisk symbols for example `*Heading 1*`, `**Heading 2**`.

I'm use regex to find strings in this format, tag them and change the style of the tags.

The item that I am struggling with is removing the asterisk symbols from the text after they've been searched. I tried some code (included by commented out) but it just removes the tagged text.

My code correctly finds `*Heading 1*` and turns it in to **`*Heading 1*`** but doesn't remove the markdown symbols to get **Heading 1**

Can anyone help me with an algorithm to remove the asterisk symbols from the headings that retains the formatting?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter import font


class HelpDialog(tk.Toplevel):
    """Seperate window to show the results of SSO Search"""
    def __init__(self, parent,text):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.title("Help")
        self.defaultfont = font.Font(family="Sans Serif",size=12)
        self.textbox = ScrolledText(self,height=40,width=80,font=self.defaultfont)
        self.textbox.config(wrap=tk.WORD)
        self.textbox.grid()


        self.textbox.insert(0.0,text)
        self.style()

    def style(self):
        self.h1font = font.Font(family="Sans Serif", size=18, weight="bold")
        self.h2font = font.Font(family="Sans Serif", size=14, weight="bold")
        self.h3font = font.Font(family="Sans Serif", size=12, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        self.textbox.tag_configure("h1",font=self.h1font)
        self.textbox.tag_configure("h2",font=self.h2font)
        self.textbox.tag_configure("h3",font=self.h3font)

        self.tag_match(r"^[\*]{1}[\w\d -]+[\*]{1}$", "h1")
        self.tag_match(r"^[\*]{2}[\w\d -]+[\*]{2}$", "h2")
        self.tag_match(r"^[\*]{3}[\w\d -]+[\*]{3}$", "h3")

    def tag_match(self,regex,tag):
        count = tk.IntVar()
        self.textbox.mark_set("matchStart", "1.0")
        self.textbox.mark_set("matchEnd", "1.0")
        while True:
            index = self.textbox.search(regex,"matchEnd","end",count=count,regexp=True)
            if index=="": break

            self.textbox.mark_set("matchStart",index)
            self.textbox.mark_set("matchEnd", "%s+%sc" % (index, count.get()))
            self.textbox.tag_add(tag,"matchStart","matchEnd")

            #Futile attempt to remove the ** from the headings
            #text = self.textbox.get("matchStart", "matchEnd")
            #orig_length = len(text)
            #text = text.replace("*","").ljust(orig_length, " ")
            #self.textbox.delete("matchStart", "matchEnd")
            #self.textbox.insert("matchStart", text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = """*Heading 1*
A paragraph
**Heading 2**
Some more text

***Heading 3***
Conclusion
"""
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    HelpDialog(root,text)
```

Comment: Do you want to literally remove them, or just hide them from view? I think _"Can anyone help me with an algorithm to parse, style and reformat the markdown headings?"_ is far too broad of a question for stack overflow.

Comment: Your commented-out attempt tries to replace the text with nothing. Why not just delete the text?

Comment: @BryanOakley I've modified the question to narrow the scope. The commented out code replaces * with <empty string>, I'm open to better ways to delete/hide these.

Comment: @BryanOakley Where I am struggling is picking the start and end points to delete. Should I be performing another search between the current "matchStart" "matchEnd" marks for * and using the result of that? Seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can use the `delete` method of the text widget to delete the characters at the start and end of the range. You can do simplified math on the indexes to adjust them. So, for example, to delete the character at "matchEnd" (which actually represents the spot just *after* the last character in the matched range) you can do `delete("matchEnd-1c")` where `-1c` is short hand for "minus one character".

At the every end of your loop inside of `tag_match`, add the following two lines:

```
self.textbox.delete("matchStart")
self.textbox.delete("matchEnd-1c")
```

However, this code assumes that the markup is just a single byte. You will need to pass information in to tell the function how many characters on each side of the text to delete, since that information doesn't otherwise exist.

For example, you could pass it in like this:

```
self.tag_match(r"^[\*]{1}[\w\d -]+[\*]{1}$", "h1", 1)
```

You will then need to adjust the code that deletes the characters to take this information into account. For example, assuming you pass that number in as the variable `n`, it would look something like this:

```
def tag_match(self, regex, tag, n):
    ...
    while True:
        ...
        self.textbox.delete("matchEnd-{}c".format(n), "matchEnd")
        self.textbox.delete("matchStart", "matchStart+{}c".format(n))
```